# Computing expectation of bivariate random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, gaussian

Let $X,Y\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ be independent standard normal random variables. Compute the expectation $E[e^{X+Y}1_{X+Y>a}]$ where $1$ is an indicator function, and $a$ is some constant.

Without the indicator function it is straightforward to compute the expectations due to independence. That is I can write $E[e^{X+Y}] = E[e^{X}]E[e^Y]$ which gives me $e$ as the answer. However, the presence of indicator function makes this slightly complicated. Am I allowed to use law of iterated expectations and start with $E[E[e^{X+Y}1_{X+Y>a}|Y]]$? Any hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since $X,Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ are independent, we know that $X+Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$. From here you may be able to just compute the expectation using integration and the equation for a Gaussian pdf? The indicator would certainly be easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I allowed to use law of iterated expectations and start

Well, yes, you may do that. $~\mathsf E\big(\mathrm e^{X+Y}\mathbf 1_{X+Y>a}\big) = \mathsf E\big(\mathrm e^Y\,\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{X}\mathbf 1_{X>a-Y}\mid Y)\big)$

---

However, if you can evaluate $\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{X}\mathbf 1_{X>a-Y}\mid Y)$, you could instead evaluate $\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{Z}\mathbf 1_{Z>a})$ when $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,2)$

Which is useful since $X+Y\sim\mathcal N(0,2)$